# Is it possible to have specific payment gateways for WooCommerce based on user role?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, elementor

I have a storefront using wordpress, elementor, and WooCommerce. My customers have to register prior and are put into 2 different sections: pay with Stripe or pay by check in 30 days. I'm using the plugin "Members" that allows me to add new roles.

I want to restrict which payment gateways are possible based on the roles. So a customer with the "Customer-Stripe" can't pay with cheque and the "Customer-Cheque" can't pay by stripe.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_payment_gateways', 'disablePaymentOptionsBasedOnRole'); 
function disablePaymentOptionsBasedOnRole( $available_gateways ) {  
    if( is_admin() ) 
        return $available_gateways;
    else{
        if (current_user_can( 'Customer-Stripe' ) ){
            unset( $available_gateways['cheque'] );
        }
        if (current_user_can( 'Customer-Cheque' ) ) {
            unset( $available_gateways['stripe'] );
        }
    }
    return $available_gateways;
}
```

I had this written up to disable the gateways but they don't seem to be working. All payment options are still available. Is there an easier way to disable payment gateways?

Comment: Have you tested user capabilities in lower case? `if (current_user_can( 'customer-stripe' ) ){`

Comment: omg it works with lowercase. Thank you so much. I've been trying to figure this out for almost 2 days. Mind adding this suggestion as an "answer" so I can flag it as the answer?

Comment: You're welcome. Good job!